# Mapping Interfaces to Methods in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface, global-asax

I was recently at a Techdays seminar, at the SOLIDify Your Microsoft ASP.MVC MVC Applications session.  The instructor had a demo that had mapping Interfaces to Methods from the Global.asax file OnApplication_Start().

So anywhere in the web application he could simply do IDate.GetMyDate() and it would return the date.

I was wondering if anyone knew how he coded it in the global.asax file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received feedback from the instructor, and he pointed me to the following website if anyone is interested.  Here is the link for the details

http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/10/24/asp-net-mvc-tip-dependency-injection-with-unity-application-block.aspx